# php mktime from variable

Tags: php, date, mktime

I have a variable like this:

```
$event_start_date_hour_ISO = str_replace(':',', ',$event_start_hour).', 0, '.date('d, m, Y', $event_start_day);
```

The `echo` result of `$event_start_date_hour_ISO` is `11, 30, 0, 06, 02, 2016`.
If I do next:

```
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime($event_start_date_hour_ISO))
```

The result is `2016-02-06T11:48:08+02:00`.

If I do:

```
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(11, 30, 0, 06, 02, 2016))
```

The result if correct:

```
2016-06-02T11:30:00+03:00
```

Except `+03:00`, my UTC+2.

What am I doing wrong? How to put data from variable and get right answer?

Comment: What is the value of $event_start_day ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand your problem. But i think you have inverted Month and day in the mktime function.

```
mktime(Hour, minute , second, month, day, year);
```

cf : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to upvote the answer and to mark as resolved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DateTime` class is useful here.

```
$event_start_day; // A timestamp 
$event_start_hour; // A string in format... H:i:s.... 13:30:00
$event_arr = explode(':', $event_start_hour);
$event_date = new DateTime();
$event_date->setTimestamp($event_start_day);
$event_date->setTime(
    $event_arr[0],
    $event_arr[1],
    $event_arr[2],
);
echo  $event_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It may also be useful to look at `DateTimeZone`.

Answer (score -1):

(Late answer but for the future)

You have to divide the variable into 6.

```
$hour="12";
$min="15";
$sec="00";
$month="03";
$date="12";
$year="2023";
```

than

```
date(DATE_ATOM, mktime($hour, $min, $sec, $month, $date, $year));
```

comma in the text variable doesn't work like real comma.